# VBScript check current Windows theme

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have written the below VBScript that changes the Windows theme to the default Windows theme however this triggers even when the Windows theme is already the default Windows theme.

How could I add some logic to check that the current Windows theme is not the default Windows theme and if it is then do nothing?

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero.theme"

For i = 1 To 10

    WScript.Sleep 1000

    If WshShell.AppActivate("Personalization") Then
        WshShell.Sendkeys "%FC"
        WshShell.Sendkeys "{F4}"
        Exit For
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can check that in the registry under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes
```

value: **CurrentTheme**

best regards